# Input fields not clearing after the validation fails

Tags: jsf

I have a form, it contains username and password etc... if i gave any wrong value the validation will fail. next if i see the form na that previously given values are coming in the input fields.. i cleared the bean values also. but the input fields are not yet cleared.

i have cleared the input fields using the following link 1st step.

https://cwiki.apache.org/MYFACES/clear-input-components.html

this is working but what the problem is this is working only in `<rich:datatable>` 1st page.
if i have navigate to second page and next pages and all that Popup panel itself not opening.

i am using the jsf version 2.0,
Please provide a good solution.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can add [OmniFaces Library](http://omnifaces.org) to your project and use their [ResetInputAjaxActionListener](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/eventlistener/ResetInputAjaxActionListener.html)

Like this

```
<h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{bean.update}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" />
    <f:actionListener type="org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Read more about it on **BalusC** blog [Reset non-processed input components on ajax update](http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/reset-non-processed-input-components-on.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using session scope ? Change it to request scope. Otherwise, add your xhtml page and bean class.