# How to remove input fields values in a form after validation fail

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF-2.2. I wrote in a mandatory input field a value. If remove it JSF writes the old value again into the input field. How can I remove or block this?

Bean:

```
public class CommentBean{

@NotNull
@Getter
@Setter
private String comment;
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:form>
 <h:inputText value="#{commentBean.comment}">

<h:commandButton
    styleClass="button"
        value="Remove"
        action="#{commentBean.save()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" resetValues="true"/>
</h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815297/input-fields-not-clearing-after-the-validation-fails and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks but I had read it before I wrote my question.
I'm looking for a solution wíthout OmniFaces Library.
My application does not work with OmniFaces.